# Python - how to create a combination of words and numbers for running commands?

Tags: python

I’m creating a small program that starts up projects from `MacOS`' `Spotlight`, as I’m tired of always opening the terminal and booting up 6 different projects every morning. `Alfred` could be used for running terminal commands, but I really want to use `Spotlight`.

A program can be made executable from `Spotlight` by changing some permissions, but arguments cannot be passed to programs on `Spotlight`.
So I thought about creating a small file for every single variation of the command I might want to run (yes that would mean hundreds of thousands of files).

The commands are always a combination of a word followed by a number or numbers (*each number represents a repo*), such as `run012345` which would run a file I created to start all 6 projects.

I wanted to make it even better so I added a few different commands, such as doing a `git pull`, opening my editor and the browser on the page(s) I need. So commands could also be like `run25pull5open2`, `pull4`, `code02pull2browser`, `run0123pull1code5`. Order of commands doesn’t matter.

So given that I have the following options for commands

```
commands = [‘run’, ‘pull’, ‘code’, ‘browser’]
```

for numbers:

```
repos = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

what would be the best way to come up with all of the combinations of commands?

Comment: is it really worth it to use thousands of files instead of another package?

Comment: Are you not allowed to generate or edit a command file on demand, like before you execute it on Spotlight?

Answer (score 1):

This code will generate all combinations of length `r` from specified list (it will create non repeating combinations of all given inputs):

```
def getAllCombinations(l, d, start, end, index, r, allCombinations = []):
    #Ending condition
    if(index == r):
        allCombinations.append([d[i] for i in range(r)])
        return allCombinations
    else:
        i = start
        
        while(i <= end and end - i + 1 >= r - index): 
            d[index] = l[i]
            i += 1
            getAllCombinations(l, d, i, end, index + 1, r, allCombinations)
            
        return allCombinations
    

numbers =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
commands = ['run', 'pull', 'code', 'browser']

main_list = numbers + commands
print(main_list)

r = 4 #specifies the combination length
d = list(range(r))

combinations = getAllCombinations(main_list, d, 0, len(main_list) - 1, 0, r)
print(combinations)
```

If you want to get combinations of length `1, 2, 3, 4 ...` just run the `getAllCombinations` few times in a loop and save the lists.